# Multistroke object in illustrator - need to make individual strokes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

I have a logo, where each letter is a 3 stroke object. I've created the object with multiple strokes, and now I need to make it into an object by removing the 'middle stroke'.

I've tried 'outline stroke' and 'compound path' but there seems to be no easy conversion to three separate strokes.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the white stroke. You merely need 2 black strokes.

Highlight one of the strokes in the **Appearance Panel** and choose `Effect > Path > Offset Path` and adjust to your liking.

[image]

Then if you need separate objects (stroke paths), use `Object > Expand Appearance` on the circle.

---

If the above doesn't solve your issue, you can use `Object > Expand Appearance` on your existing artwork. Followed possibly by `Object > Expand` and then click the `Merge` button on the Pathfinder Panel.